# Running C++ as FastCGI in Lighttpd

Tags: c++, fastcgi, lighttpd

I'm trying to run C++ binaries as FastCGI in Lighttpd, but it won't start. I tried something like this:

```
fastcgi.server += (".cpp" =>
        ( "localhost" =>
            (
                "socket" => "/tmp/mysocket",
                "bin-path" => "/var/www/index.cpp",
                "max-procs" => 1
        ))
)
```

But I can't get it working. I want to keep the C++ in memory for starting really fast.

Comment: You don't run C++ source files. You run the compiled executable. So you need to compile your `index.cpp` into a `myapp.fcgi` binary, perhaps with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g -O index.cpp -lfcgi -o myapp.fcgi` then you need to configure your `lighttpd` to use that `myapp.fcgi`

Answer (score 2):

You should adapt your configuration to something like this:

```
  fastcgi.server = (
    "/api" => (
      "api.fastcgi.handler" => (
        "socket" => "/var/run/lighttpd/lighttpd-fastcgi-test-" + PID + ".socket",,
        "check-local" => "disable",
        "bin-path" => "/var/www/localhost/cgi-bin/test.fcgi",
        "max-procs" => 30,
      )
    )
  )
```

For all requests: localhost/api/some_test lighttp will call your fcgi executable /var/www/localhost/cgi-bin/test.fcgi

Comment: Also, the C++ source file should be *compiled* into `test.fcgi`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch right, for example of configuration file for lighttp your fastcgi executable should be named as test.fcgi and in path: /var/www/localhost/cgi-bin/test.fcgi